# Как объединить элементы массива в строку

Tags: javascript

В силу своего незнания набросал код который объединяет элементы массива в строку. В c#, например, можно было сделать

```
var str = string.Joint(";", Список);
```

А как такое же сделать в `js`?

```
var x= "";
params.value.forEach(function(item, i, params) {
  x+=params[i].display_name+";";
});

return x.slice(0, -1);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все тоже самое

```js
var array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
console.log(array.join(';'));
```

[Описание метода join](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

---

возможно вам поможет что-то такое:

```
params.value.map(function(elem){
    return elem.display_name;
}).join(";");

/* ES6
 params.value.map(elem =>elem.display_name).join(";");
*/
```

на рабочем массиве объектов это выглядит так:

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [
  {name: "Joe", age: 22},
  {name: "Kevin", age: 24},
  {name: "Peter", age: 21}
]

// ES6
var result = arrayOfObjects.map(elem => elem.name).join(";");
console.log(result);

// ES5
var result = arrayOfObjects.map(function(elem){
    return elem.name;
}).join(";");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: не работает для моего кода. return params.value.join(';') это код возвращает Object object, Object object...

Comment: @Radzhab очевидно, что проблема в вашем  `params.value`, которые являются объектом, а не одиночными значениями массива

Comment: Алексей, если бы мне это помогло)) Я далек от js. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @Radzhab нужно визуальное представление params.value и необходимый output из него. можно (**нужно**) добавить в вопрос. без этого пока вопрос сводится к тому, что описано в ответе))

Comment: ну просто надо оптимизировать этот код `var x= "";
params.value.forEach(function(item, i, params) {
  x+=params[i].display_name+";";
});

return x.slice(0, -1);`

Comment: это индуский код по сути

Comment: @Radzhab ну на самом деле в данном случае когда у вас массив  объектов с полями - по другому и никак. тут просто придется пробегаться по объектам и конкатинировать только нужные поля...максимум что можно перевести в стрелочную нотацию

Comment: @Radzhab добавил возможный вариант склеить элементы. Даже в стиле ES6 что будет еще короче

Comment: @АлексейШиманский только подумал предложить вариант с `map` :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот:

```js
var array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'].join(';');
console.log(array);
console.log(typeof array);
```

Но если вы хотите чтобы это снова стало массивом

```js
var array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'].join(';');
console.log(array);
console.log(typeof array);
array = array.split(';');
console.log(array);
console.log(typeof array);
```

Ну и бонус

```js
var array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'].join(';');
console.log(array);
console.log(typeof array);
array = array.replace(/[;]/g, ";|");
array = array.split('|');
console.log(array);
console.log(typeof array);
```

Comment: не работает для моего кода. return params.value.join(';') это код возвращает Object

Comment: Чему тогда равен `params`

Comment: Это как я понимаю object.....

Comment: Я не спрашиваю какого типа переменная, а чему она равна.